# google API translate, only a div into page

Tags: javascript, translation, google-api

I have an HTML page, and I would use Google Translate to translate only a div into my page.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'it'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

With this code, google translate everything in the page. But if I wanna translate only a piece. How I can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the examples at [Google AJAX Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/).

```
google.language.translate("Hello world", "en", "es", function(result) {
  if (!result.error) {
    var container = document.getElementById("translation");
    container.innerHTML = result.translation;
  }
});
```

use `innerHTML` to get hold of the contents of your DIV. You may have to strip out formatting first, though.

Comment: I see in the example given here you are using google.language.translate, may I know how you have initialized variable google ? I tried to go through the docs and the only JS support I found was node JS so how can I use it on client side ?

Answer (score 2):

ok, but how to open any named `<div>` of a internet web page in my page with `<iframe>` tag?  Is it possible in general, not to display (in iframe) the whole page, but only the part of it (without balast arround)?

I know e.g. this for whole pages :

```
<div>
  <iframe src ="http://www.colosseum.cz/vzdelavani-a-informace/zpravy" width="98%" height="600" style="border: 3px;">
    <p>unsupported</p>
  </iframe> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using the script instead of the API. You can add a `notranslate` class to all elements that you don't want translated.

You can try it here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate

Try changing the `h1` tag to

```
<h1 class="notranslate">My Web Page</h1>
```

Answer found here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/translating-only-a-portion-of-page