# Google API translator. How can I translate only one DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-translate

How can I modify this code to translate the only one container on page with id #lyrics?

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ru', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ok, I'm replace 'google_translate_element' to 'lyrics', but I have the same result

Comment: Sorry. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1900203/2732991).

Comment: I've seen this answer, but I can't apply this to my code, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this function:

```
function googleSectionalElementInit() {
  new google.translate.SectionalElement({
    sectionalNodeClassName: 'lyrics',
    controlNodeClassName: 'translate-lyrics',
    background: 'trasparent'
  }, 'google_sectional_element');
}
```

Comment: Showing SectionalElement is not a constructor error.

Comment: Throws error: Uncaught TypeError: google.translate.SectionalElement is not a constructor

Answer (score 6):

you can add class call notranslate into the body or the meta tag of the class 
then add the class translate into the div whom you want to translate its poor approach but it sure do you wok  e.g

```
<body class="notranslate">

<h1>no translate paragraph</h1>

<h1 class="translate"> i want to translate the line</h1>
</body>
```