# How can google translate api can translate some text with specific class 'translate' not the whole webpage

Tags: php, jquery

[Google API translator. How can I translate only one DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983367/google-api-translator-how-can-i-translate-only-one-div)

Comment: I had tried this link but not working, I think I'm on a wrong way, can anyone please help me?

Comment: <body>
<div class="translate">
Hello
</div>
<h1>Friends</h1>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</body>

Comment: I had tried this but it translate the whole page, I want to translate only text with class 'translate'