# How to translate a Indian language to English (only part of text)

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to translate English to other languages and vice versa(whole website using google translate) but my question is I want to translate only one paragraph from my website. But not able to translate the part content from my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
 function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: 
      google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 
      'google_translate_element');
   }
```

Here above code represents google translate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google API translator. How can I translate only one DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983367/google-api-translator-how-can-i-translate-only-one-div)

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will be helpful: [Translate Content with the Google Translate API and JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/google-translate-api)

Here is another helpful link: [Translating text with Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate_translate_text-nodejs)

To create a link that automatically translates your Website Translator-enabled page without prompting your users, uses the parameter `#googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE)`.

If you want to translate your block from Hindi to English, simple by this link below.

So, for example, the link `http://translate.google.com/support/#googtrans(hi|en)` automatically translates the page `http://translate.google.com/support/` into English.

You can refer the list of language codes here: [List of ISO 639-1 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)

You also can refer this link to see more about translating written words by Google Translate: [Translate written words](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142478?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop)

Comment: my point here is translating Hindi to English. And I want to translate only one div from my website not a whole website.

Comment: Oh sorry for that, I just edited my answer. I hope it will help.

Comment: getting this error after referring first link.         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined